# Why is my dot product for checking orthogonality not zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

There is this simple problem in my book:
Project the first vector orthogonally into the line spanned by the second vector:
$\overrightarrow{V}=\begin{pmatrix}2  \cr 1\end{pmatrix},\overrightarrow{S}=\begin{pmatrix}3  \cr 0\end{pmatrix} $

So I follow the formula for converting a basis into an orthogonal one : $Proj[\overrightarrow{s}]\overrightarrow{(V)}=\left(\frac{\overrightarrow{V}\cdot\overrightarrow{S}
}{\overrightarrow{S}\cdot\overrightarrow{S}}\right)\overrightarrow{S}$ and get $\begin{pmatrix}2  \cr 0\end{pmatrix}$, which is the correct answer according to the answer key. However, when I check with the dot product for $\begin{pmatrix}2  \cr 0\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}2  \cr 1\end{pmatrix}$ I do not get zero like I should. Am I interpreting the concept of orthogonal projection wrong? The checking part with the dot product is not part of the original problem, I just thought I would do it to see if I understand orthogonality correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The projection $Proj_u[v]$ is not orthogonal to $u$, instead $v-Proj_u[v]$ is orthogonal to $u$. Here that difference is $(0,1)$ which is indeed perpendicular to $(3,0)$.

Comment: Oh ok! So in this case, I was checking against the original vector and not the actual projection (which is found by the Gram-Schmidt process)?

Comment: @InnerSpeaker No, you were dotting with the projection. It is just that the projection isn't orthogonal to the line you project onto. You can draw a right triangle to see the whole picture; the projection is one leg, the original vector is the hypotenuse, and the other leg is the difference between them.